# How do you send a JSON encoded object to a PHP function that takes a PHP class object as a variable?

Tags: php, json, zend-framework

I have a java aplet that is sending a JSON encoded object to a Zend Framework JSON Server.

the problem that I have is the code is setup like this:

ServerController:

```
public function jsonAction()
{

$server = new Zend_Json_Server();
$Server->setClass('Application_Model_ClassObject', 'co');

if('GET' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])
{
    $server->setTarget('...')
           ->setEnvelope(Zend_Json_Server_Smd::ENV_JSONRPC_2);
    $smd = $server->getServiceMap();

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $smd;
    return
}

echo $server->handle();
}
```

ClassObject function:

```
/**
* DoSomethign description
* @param ClassObject
*/
public function doSomething(Application_Model_ClassObject $obj)
{

    $someVariable = $obj->getSomeValue();
    ...
}
```

I get an error response from the server saying that `obj` needs to be an instance of `ClassObject`

Comment: How do you work with the json reponse? I mean could you show how you put the stuff from `$_GET['something']` to your function `doSomething(...)`

Comment: Could you show us anything about that `ClassObject`? You need to instantiate one and populate it with data.

Comment: Where is the json decoded to an object?

Comment: You specify the name of your class in the old style of formatting for namespacing. Therefore your type hint needs to be `Application_Model_ClassObject` rather than `ClassObject`. I am only assuming this because of line 4 of your code snippet.

Comment: Sorry i have checked the code and corrected the snippet, both of the formatting is the same.

Comment: looks like you could do with some time on the Zend Framework manual pages: you're not using the request object, not using the view helpers/scripts, manually setting headers... either use the framework as it is intended, or don't use it at all. this half and half approach is asking for trouble. Also: provide the code in which you're actually calling the `doSomething` method

Answer (score 1):

Ok so this is what we ended up doing (Quick and dirty version)... Although i believe there is a better way.

1. Removed the type-hint so that the function will be able to receive any data.
2. Create a new function in "Application_Model_ClassObject" that will handle an array of data or an object.
3. Added a few extra lines to "doSomething" so that the rest can go on as normal.

Here are some details:

```
/**
* DoSomethign description
* @param ClassObject
*/
public function doSomething($data)
{
    $obj = new Application_Model_ClassObject();
    $obj->populate($data);

    $someVariable = $obj->getSomeValue();
    ...
}

/**
*
* Application_Model_ClassObject class
*/
class Application_Model_ClassObject
{
    ...

    public function populate($row)
    {
        if (is_array($row)) {
        $row = new ArrayObject($row, ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS);
        }

        if (isset ($row->SomeValue)) {
        $this->setSomeValue($row->SomeValue);
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you remove the type hint "ClassObject", then the doSomething method will accept any data that comes in. Then it's up to the doSomething method to decode the json string, and do something useful with it.

Comment: There might be a reason for the typehint :). Maybe a certain method the function expects. `ClassObject` can even be a clumsily named interface. I would not advise to change it.

Comment: Type hints are usually there for a reason. Removing them because of an error is not advisable and will probably cause the class to fail in some other way.

Comment: The doSomething method receives JSON data straight from the JSON server. Since there is no class-mapping available for the JSON server, the incoming data can only be of a standard PHP type. This way it makes sense to either remove the type hint, or change it to something more generic like "array".

If you were to use a Zend_Soap_Server on the other hand, then you would have class-mapping available. And then it would make sense to have complex type hinting in your entry points for your API.

Answer (score -3):

> public function doSomething(ClassObject obj) { ... }

Um, usually you don't write PHP functions like that, as it's not strongly typed. Normally, it looks like this instead:

public function doSomething($obj) {...}

It looks like you've tried to write a PHP function with some Java syntax mixed in.

Comment: You can do type hints in PHP functions too.

Comment: It's perfectly possible to add a typehint to your method definition, like the author did. Classes are supported, as are arrays. Other basic types are not (yet) supported AFAIK.

Comment: So it becomes more a question of if you should, as it would incur extraneous effort for OP here. (Copying the data structure from a plain data object into a `ClassObject` manually.)

Comment: Ah, wonderful. I wasn't aware of that. Sorry about the confusion.